# Redundancy in Solve

Tags: equation-solving, algebraic-manipulation

```
Solve[{
       a[1] a[2] == a[3] a[4],
       a[1]^2 == a[4]^2,
       a[1] a[3] == a[2] a[4],
       a[2]^2 == a[3]^2
     }]
```

returns

```
{
 {a[3] -> -a[2], a[4] -> -a[1]},
 {a[3] -> a[2], a[4] -> a[1]},
 {a[2] -> 0, a[3] -> 0, a[4] -> -a[1]},
 {a[2] -> 0, a[3] -> 0, a[4] -> a[1]},
 {a[1] -> 0, a[3] -> -a[2], a[4] -> 0},
 {a[1] -> 0, a[3] -> a[2], a[4] -> 0}
}
```

As you see, the last four solutions are redundant. Is there a way to avoid this somehow?

Of course in this case one can easily do it "by hand", but if one has some huge system, it could be not so easy to detect this kind of redundancy.

Comment: @Bill I can't, that's why I am asking. There might be in fact two possibilities - just process the output of `Solve` to remove solutions that are particular cases of other solutions; or maybe invoke some features of `Solve` that I am not aware of, to eliminate those redundant solutions from the beginning.

Comment: In fact I now think I can propose something for the first possibility: say something like remove those solutions `s` with the property that for some other solution `t` one has `t/.s == s`.

Comment: @Bill Yes, this works - I mean, the output detects places of redundant solutions as those where `True` occurs at non-diagonal slots of your `Outer`. I don't see however whether this will work in all cases...

Comment: @Bill I believe it is much simpler. Each solution describes a set. Totality of solutions is the union of these sets. If some of these sets are included in others, I call these redundant. They are not needed to describe the union. For that you only need those solutions which correspond to maximal sets (maximal in the sense of inclusion, that is).

Comment: Of course there are cases when you do not have any maximal sets - like e. g. an ascending chain $S_1\subset S_2\subset\cdots$. But if you have finite amount of solutions you always can single out the maximal ones explicitly.

Comment: @Bill Yes, that would be a possible solution. I just suspect there might be something much more efficient built into Mathematica somehow.